# find rows in Table1 that match criteria rows in Table2

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've got two tables:

1. `T1` is a table of data

   - column `one` cannot have `null`
   - column `two` and `three` can have `null`s
2. `T2` is a table of categorization rules

   - it has the same columns as `T1` along with a `cat` column to represent the category
   - the idea is that the first three columns have criteria used to determine how and if rows in `T1` should be categorized
   - it is possible that a row in `T2` could have values in 2+ columns meaning there are multiple criteria that need to match in `T1` (e.g. `T1.two like "2*" and T1.three like "hi"`)

I want a query that finds the rows in `T1` that match based on the criteria in `T2`. Here is an example:

```
+------+------+-------+
| T1                  |
+------+------+-------+
| one  | two  | three |
+------+------+-------+
| aaaa | 1111 |       |
| bbbb | 2222 |       |
| cccc |      | test  |
| dddd |      |       |
+------+------+-------+

+------+-----+-------+------+
| T2                        |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| one  | two | three | cat  |
+------+-----+-------+------+
| aaaa | *   | *     |    1 | -> all rows in T1 where column one equals aaaa
| *    | 2*  | *     |    2 | -> all rows in T1 where column two starts with 2
| *    | *   | test  |    3 | -> all rows in T1 where column three equals test
| *    | 3*  | hi    |    3 | -> all rows in T1 where column two starts with 3 AND column 3 equals hi
+------+-----+-------+------+
```

I've got `*` in `T2` because I am trying to say the value in those columns should not matter. So using the second row as an example I'm saying match all rows in T1 where:

- `one` is anything
- `two` starts with 2
- `three` is anything

My thought was to do an ambiguous join and that filter on matching rows:

```
SELECT T1.one, T2.one, T1.two, T2.two, T1.three, T2.three, T2.id
FROM T1, T2
WHERE
    (T1.one Like [T2].[one])                             ' match column one
    AND (T1.two Is Null Or T1.two Like [T2].[two])       ' match column two; the "is null" is needed in case the value is not there in T1
    AND (T1.three Is Null Or T1.three Like [T2].[three]) ' match column three; the "is null" is needed in case the value is not there in T1
```

This results in the table below. It partially works but returns rows it should not (marked below).

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+----+
| Result                                                       |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+----+
| T1.one | T2.one | T1.two | T2.two | T1.three | T2.three | cat|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+----+
| aaaa   | aaaa   |   1111 | *      |          | *        |  1 | 
| aaaa   | *      |   1111 | *      |          | test     |  3 | -> THIS SHOULD NOT BE RETURNED
| bbbb   | *      |   2222 | 2*     |          | *        |  2 | 
| bbbb   | *      |   2222 | *      |          | test     |  3 | -> THIS SHOULD NOT BE RETURNED
| cccc   | *      |        | 2*     | test     | *        |  2 | -> THIS SHOULD NOT BE RETURNED
| cccc   | *      |        | *      | test     | test     |  3 | 
| dddd   | *      |        | 2*     |          | *        |  2 | -> THIS SHOULD NOT BE RETURNED
| dddd   | *      |        | *      |          | test     |  3 | -> THIS SHOULD NOT BE RETURNED
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+----+
```

I've started at this for a few hours but I cannot figure out how to do what I need.

I figure this is not a database-specific question but if it matters I'm trying to do this with MS Access 2013.

Comment: I can't grasp what you want... Can you further explain? You want rows from T1 where the equivalent fields in T2 are null or equal to T1?

Comment: are there actually asterisk in your table?

Comment: you should have used OR instead of AND in your WHERE clause

Comment: @PatB: I added some more details. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Gene: Yes, because I am trying to say the value in those columns should not matter.

Comment: If you're only looking for fields that match between the two table why would you have data that "should not matter?" Using like, or using the asterisks in the table means that everything will always match. You never rule anything out. The only time something would be ruled out if there was actually two separate pieces of data you were comparing. Based on the query you provided, why should the second line be discarded? it matches every part of your where statement.

Comment: The columns in `T2` are joined with AND so I'm saying a row in `T1` should match if `one` AND `two` AND `three` matches. So if in `T2` we only care about criteria in `one` then `two` and `three` would be wildcards, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I think I figured out a working answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/595eb/1.

Instead of using `*` (wildcard) in `T2` I use `null` and then in the query check if the value is `null`. This seems to have the desired/expected result.

```
WHERE
  (T2.one is null or T1.one = T2.one) AND
  (T2.two is null or T1.two like T2.two) AND
  (T2.three is null or T1.three like T2.three);
```

There will be duplicates if multiple rows in `T2` matche a row in `T1` so I'm still working on figuring that out.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you have 2 problems: you cannot join tables on computed fields.

-> all rows in T1 where column two starts with 2
-> all rows in T1 where column two starts with 3 AND column 3 equals hi

cannot be done this way.

However, I suggest you use sql fiddle to show your example.

I have done it for you.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb1fc/2

Comment: THERE IS A FIDDLE SITE FOR SQL? Where have you been all my life. I've been wishing there was something like this. I'll check it out when I get home. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.one, T2.one, T1.two, T2.two, T1.three, T2.three, T2.id
FROM T2 LEFT JOIN T1 
on t1.one = t2.one and t1.two = t2. two and t1.three = t2.three
```

You can't compare columns using `like` unless you specify a pattern.

Comment: That is why I put `*` in the values in `T2` so I could use `like`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.one, T2.one, T1.two, T2.two, T1.three, T2.three, T2.ID
FROM T1, T2
WHERE (t1.one LIKE t2.one + '*'
AND t1.two LIKE t2.two + '*'
AND t1.three LIKE t2.three + '*')
OR t1.one LIKE t2.one + '*'
OR t1.two LIKE t2.two + '*'
OR t1.three LIKE t2.three + '*'
```

Comment: There might be a situation where a row in `T2` has criteria in two columns in which case both need to match to be valid.

Comment: I've got a lot more columns and I feel like this kind of SQL could get complicated quickly.